# JSON data not displaying in NSTableView

Tags: json, swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am fairly new to `Swift` but I have a `NSTableView` that is not displaying any of my data.  My `JSON` data is being printed in the console perfectly and I thought that my `cellView` would display in my `textField` all my values but I get nothing back.  I have my `Table` set up to where my 'Table Cell View' has an identifier of 'cell' so I believe they are linked correctly.  I am not receiving any errors in the console but my data is still not displaying.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!

var values: NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    get();


}


override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {

    }
}

func get(){

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://myurl")

    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL);

    values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data,options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

    tableView.reloadData();


    print(values);

}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {

    return self.values.count;
}

private func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "cell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    cellView.textField!.stringValue = self.values.object(at: row) as! String


    return cellView
}
```

Comment: Probably its because you parsing data directly so better use GCD to parse data and then in main thread , Reload Tableview

Comment: Are your delegate methods getting called? Does the table have the expected number of rows (even if they're empty)?

Comment: The number of rows is based on the count of the values which is represented in my numbersOfRows function

Comment: I understand that, but I'm asking if that function is actually being called - add a ``print("called")`` line to that function and see if *called* appears in the console at runtime.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.  Now taking another look at it, it seems that my numberOfRows function is not being called.  I guess I am unsure how to incorporate that into my tableView function.

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure your table view knows it's delegate and data source?, if not, add this to viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: I added these lines and had no change in my result.  Still my data is not being displayed in my table while my console shows the data in JSON form.

Comment: '(
        {
        featured = 0;
        id = 1;
        "product_description" = "Test Description";
        "product_download" = "download link";
        "product_image" = Image;
        "product_name" = "The Raven";
        "product_price" = "29.99";
        "product_video" = "video link";
    }
)
'

Comment: what key from these keys you want to display, each value in values array is a dictionary not a string

Comment: I wanted to display the values of all my keys.  I thought that casting my cellView 'as! String' would have accomplished this.

Comment: you're not casting the cellView to string, you're casting a value object from values array, and each vale is a dictionary not a sting, to make sure, let the textField.stringValue = to a string value of any of these keys, for example the value of the key product_description

Comment: I guess I do not yet understand the syntax on how to do that.  I will have to look into it.

Comment: I am not sure how to access my key values when my json data has no title.

Comment: try this, cellView.textField!.stringValue =  (self.values.object(at: row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "product_description") as? String

Comment: Thank you for the code.  I now understand what you mean.  Unfortunately i still had no difference in my result.  Perhaps I have my table set up incorrectly or something.  I am not too sure why it is not working.

Comment: i am sorry i couldn't solve your problem, but to be honest i am not really familiar with macOS development, i am an iOS developer after all, best of luck Nick

Comment: Ya same here...that is the issue.  There is almost little to no documentation or tutorials on how to do this for macOS.  There is tons of documentation on how to do this for iOS but it is drastically different both in syntax and methodology on how to accomplish such a simple task.